# sql getting data three columns from one table and one from another

Tags: sql

I have two tables sales and customers
from 1st table I want to sum two columns recived_amount and bill_amount and subtract them both and after that also want to get customer_id

from 2nd table I just want to get Customer_name

I've tried

```
  SELECT Customer_details.CUS_name, 
       SUM(SALES.Bill_Amount) - SUM(SALES.Recived_Amount),
       Customer_details.Cus_id
  from sales 
  INNER JOIN Customer_details 
       ON Customer_details.Cus_id=sales.Cus_id
  where SALES.Cus_id = 1 order BY Cus_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT Customer_details.CUS_name, (SUM(SALES.Bill_Amount) - SUM(SALES.Recived_Amount)) as       Subtract,Customer_details.Cus_id

 from sales INNER JOIN Customer_details ON Customer_details.Cus_id=sales.Cus_id

 where SALES.Cus_id = 1 

 group by Customer_details.CUS_name,Customer_details.Cus_id

 order BY Cus_id
```

Comment: Column 'Customer_details.Cus_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: check it now and tell me

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer_details.CUS_name,
       (SUM(SALES.Bill_Amount)-SUM(SALES.Recived_Amount)) AS Balance_Owed,
       Customer_details.Cus_ID
FROM Sales INNER JOIN Customer_details ON Customer_details.Cus_id=Sales.Cus_id
GROUP BY Customer_details.CUS_name,Customer_details.Cus_id
ORDER BY Customer_details.Cus_id;
```